# How to add a framework as a dependency of a library project?

Tags: macos, xcode4

I have a library project that depends on a framework. With application target, it's easy: just add it to "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" in "Summary" tab. There is no such tab for libraries. I *do* have Framework Search Paths pointing to a proper location containing the framework directory, but framework's headers still can't be found.

How would I specify a framework as a dependency?

Comment: I'm facing similar problem - have you find a solution?

Comment: @delirus I gave up before getting the answer and just installed the framework into system location.

Answer (score 1):

You can add frameworks to the "Link Binary With Library" list in the "Build Phases" tab of your library target.
If your framework is a subproject of your library project, you can also define it as a build dependency on this tab by dragging it into the "Target Dependencies" list.